# Emacs 24.5.1 search and replace

Tags: emacs

I can find the string I'm looking for by using Ctrl+s, but then I cannot figure out how to replace it at all. Even though there is something in the status bar that kind of seems like it's telling me how to replace, it's not clear enough for me and I cannot do it.

Comment: M-x `replace-string`?

Comment: I don't know how to use that. Where do I put the words that are supposed to be replaced? It keeps giving me a word that it wants to replace, but I didn't tell it to replace that word, and in fact, the word doesn't exist in the file. Please explain further how I'm supposed to use that.

Comment: Alt+s, type the word you want to replace, enter, type the word you want to replace it with, enter, then y for each instance. There might be more elegant ways, but that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Find and replace can be done by the shortcut `Alt + %`, 
(in most of the keyboard layouts you will have to do `Alt + Shift + 5`)

2) Enter your search string and then `[ret]`followed by the  string you want to replace your search string with and again `[ret]`.

3) You can press `y` to replace a given instance of the search string or press `n` to keep it as it is, you can also press `!` to replace all the occurrences of the search string (`Shift + 1`).

There are various other options available after step 2 which can be viewd by pressing the `?` key (`Shift + /`).